# Update Statement Condition Fail

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-update, conditional-statements

I have this code which works perfectly but only problem I have is that when I enter an username or a password which does not exists in the database this code still displays the message " password changed successfully" ,without any change in db or error message.
I want to know a way to handle this. Is there a way to display a message when `WHERE` condition fails??

```
Try
        If txtBoxSettingNewPassword.Text = txtBoxSettingConfPassword.Text Then
            con.Open()
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
            cmd.CommandText = ("UPDATE [User] " & _
            "SET password = '" & (txtBoxSettingNewPassword.Text) & "'" & _
            "WHERE user_name ='" & (txtBoxSettingUserName.Text) & "'" & " and password = '" & (txtBoxSettingOldPassword.Text) & "';")
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("password changed successfully")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Passwords do not match")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong," & ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();     ----- then check the value of rowsaffected

Comment: Your code is wide open to SQL Injection. Use a stored procedure as a go between.  Your stored procedure can then be made to throw an exception when something is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move your

```
MessageBox.Show("password changed successfully")
```

outside the If block as everytime when you do the update, whether it is successful or not, the message will be displayed as there is no code to make the check if it sucessfull or not.

You can try like this:

```
cmd = New OleDbCommand("update .....", cn)
rowCount = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
If rowCount < 1 Then
MessageBox.Show("password changed successfully")
```

**On a side note:**

Your code is open to SQL Injection. You need to use paramterized query to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL update command does not error if it does not find a match.

Your call to ExecuteNonQuery has a return value which you can assign to an integer. e.g.

```
numRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

If this value is zero, you did not find a match, so you should report the error.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a bit of defensive coding here and check the user exists before running the update rather than relying on the catch. It's not as efficient because there are two database round trips.

Leave try/catch for unexpected errors...not ones you know might occur.